# How to solve vector equations?

Tags: calculus, vectors

I don't know what is meant when asked the following;

I am asked, for the vector function F determine wether the equation $\nabla \phi = F$ has a solution and determine $\phi$ .

for

$(2xyz^3 ,-x^2z^3-2y, 3x^2yz^2)$

But I don't know what is being asked.

Am I supposed to calculate the partial derivatives with respect to x, y and z for each component?

For example, should I find

$\partial/\partial x = 2yz^{3}$

$\partial/\partial y= -2$

$\partial/\partial z= 6x^{2}yz$

Or do I integrate each component or something? I am just confused on what is going on. Please help to explain.

Of course I want to understand this specific example but I mostly want to understand in general what is going on. Thank you

Update: From the comments I am seeing I am really just lost. I think I need to see it actually worked out. It is only one of many more examples I will do later but I am lost

Comment: No you're being asked to go backwards from the gradient to find the function you took the gradient of to have the vector field you started with

Comment: So for first compotent I want to find what integral evaulautes to 2xyz^3 when integrated with respect to x?

Comment: By switching both you're still backwards :) You want a function whose partial derivative with respect to $x$ is $2xyz^3$, etc, to *integrate* what you were given.

Comment: Thanks, When I do that I get $F=(x^2yz^3, -x^2z^3y-y^2, x^2yz^3)$ but what do I do from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being asked to find a function $\phi$ such that the vector field $F$ that you have been given is the gradient of $\phi$. We know that

$$\nabla \phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \hat{i} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} \hat{j} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} \hat{k}$$

and

$$ F = (2xyz^{3}) \hat{i} - (x^2z^3 + 2y)\hat{j} + (3x^2yz^2)\hat{k} $$

If we set $\nabla \phi = F$, we get three differential equations:

$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = 2xyz^{3}$$
$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = -x^2z^3 - 2y$$
$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} = 3x^2yz^2$$

These can all be solved using partial integration. You can then combine the results to find a function $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi = F$ (if such a function exists). As user runaround mentioned, you can check existence of $\phi$ by checking if $\nabla \times F = 0$. If $\nabla \times F \neq 0$, then no such $\phi$ exists since a gradient vector field is always curl-free.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you. We have not learned about curl yet. So would I get that $F=(x^2yz^3, -x^2z^3y-y^2, x^2yz^3)$

Comment: @PersonaA No, that's not correct. You are looking for $\phi(x,y,z)$, which is a scalar function, not a vector field. So your answer should be a scalar function of $x, y$ and $z$.

Comment: So I want to find a function that gives me the first compotent I have above as the partial of that function with respect to x, the second compotent be the partial with respect to y, etc?

Comment: Yes. Such a function $\phi$ does not exist in this case, however, because $\nabla \times F \neq 0$. Regardless, you should try to show that such a $\phi$ does not exist for the given $F$. The strategy I presented is in general correct for finding a potential function $\phi$ given a vector field $F$.

Answer (score 1):

The question has part of in application of calculus in physics. Ypu need to verify $curl \vec F = 0$ to determine if there exists $\phi$ such that $F = \nabla \phi$. $\phi$ is called potential in physics

Once you confirm there exisrs a $phi$, you can try to integrate partially and combine three to get $\phi$

I believe $curl \vec F \ne 0$, so there is no potential.